# How to print uncommon value between 2 array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, set-difference

I wanna compare value that stored in filename[i] and filename[j] and print out the value in filename[i] that do not have the same filename as in filename[j]. I know it is possible to do using set_difference and sort solution but I do not know exactly to write the sort and set_differences code. Here i provide my original code so that u can test it out and more understand what I'm trying to do.

my full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //important when to make random filename- srand(time(0))
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp> //important when using opencv
#include <vector>   //when using vector function

using namespace std;
using namespace cv; //important when using opencv

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

vector<String> filenames;
int a, i;
srand(time(0)); //seed random filenames - for random filename


// Get all jpg in the folder

cv::glob("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\Aggressive\\abc", filenames);

for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++)
{
    Mat im = imread(filenames[i]); //read the filename location


   std::cout << "\n";

    std::size_t found = filenames[i].find_last_of("//\\");
    //std:cout << " file: " << filenames[j].substr(found + 1) << '\n'; //display filename and its format (.jpg)

    std::string::size_type const p(filenames[i].substr(found + 1).find_last_of('.')); //eg: 2.jpg then it will find the last '.'
    std::string file_without_extension = filenames[i].substr(found + 1).substr(0, p); //eg: 2
    std::cout << " file : " << filenames[i].substr(found + 1).substr(0, p); //display filename without .jpg



}

cout << "\n";
cout << "There's " << filenames.size() << " files in the current directory.\n" << endl; // total file in the specific directory

cout << "Enter array size: \n";
cin >> a;

for (int j = 0; j < filenames.size(); j++) {
    //generate random filename
    int index = rand() % filenames.size(); //random based on total of the file in the directory
    //cout << filenames[index] << endl; //display the random number but might be redundant

    //swap filenames[j] with filenames[index]
    string temp = filenames[j];
    filenames[j] = filenames[index];
    filenames[index] = temp;
}

for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {

    //cout << "Random image selected:" << filenames[j] << endl; //basically to avoid the redundant random filename

    Mat im = imread(filenames[j]); //read filename location

    std::size_t found = filenames[j].find_last_of("//\\");
    //std:cout << " file: " << filenames[j].substr(found + 1) << '\n'; //display filename and its format (.jpg)

    std::string::size_type const p(filenames[j].substr(found + 1).find_last_of('.')); //eg: 2.jpg then it will find the last '.' 
    std::string file_without_extension = filenames[j].substr(found + 1).substr(0, p); //eg: 2
    std::cout << " file: " << filenames[j].substr(found + 1).substr(0, p); //display filename without .jpg

    string written_directory = "C:/Users/x/Documents/folder/" + filenames[j].substr(found + 1).substr(0, p) + ".jpg"; // write filename based on its original filename.
    imwrite(written_directory, im);

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you have? What do you want to get? It seems like you have 2 arrays of `std::string`. You want to print all elements which are in one array, but not the other. I can't quite understand if and why you want to sort it? Can you tell me what I got right?

Comment: actually for the array 1 it display all the filename in the one folder while in the array 2 i had a random filename based on the size of array that an user entered. so my objective now is i wanna print out all the filename that do not have in array 2. that is why i wanna to sort both array and set the difference between these array so that i can print out the value that do not have the same filename.

Comment: The standard library has you covered: [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I already try to do the code based on what I understand from that but it seem that i did a lot of mistakes. So it does not work for me sadly. Btw I'm beginner to programming so I do not really understand how it works.

Comment: @WBuck what do means by 'array' are small enough? and how to do with quadratic approach?

Comment: @AimiNazirah you can call `std::sort()` on both arrays, then call `std::set_difference()` on the sorted arrays.

Comment: I do not understand your question and its releation to your posted code. I offer to write the complete code to you, if you can describe better what you want to do. I do not see 2 arrays. What is Mat. What is imread. Can you show more of your code?

Comment: @LouisCloete actually i do not know how to call sort() for those arrays. if it not too much, can you show me the proper way to call sort() function?

Comment: @ArminMontigny imread is actually to read the whole file in the folder of directory while imwrite is used to copy the file to another directory. As you can see for array 1 is used to read all the file in the directory - basically print out all the file in the location folder and array 2 is to an array where I read random file and save the file in another directory. So now my objective is to print out all the file that do not have same filename in the array 2.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is a perfect example of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). From you question, from your code and even from the comments, people do not really understand what you want to do. With that I mean, what do you want to achieve?

It is a vague guess that you want to copy a specified number of random selected JPEG files from one directory to the other. And that you want to show the filenames of the files that will not be copied.

Let me give you some examples, what is the reason for all this confusion.

First and most important, you do not show the full code. Definitions and variable types and functions are misssing an. This is also not a [Minimum, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And the description in your question is hard to understand.

> I have two set of array

You have "two set array"? Do you mean, you have 2 `[std::set][3]` of `[std::array][3]`. Or maybe you have simply 2 `[std::vector][3]` of `std::string`. From what we can see in the code, we could assume a `std::vector<std::string>>`, but we do not know, because you did not show the feinition of "filenames".

Then, you are talking about "2" something. But we do see only **one** "filenames". So, 2 or 1?

in a comment you are writing

> in the array 2 i had a random filename based on the size of array that an user entered

My guess is that you do not want to have a random filename, but you want to select filenames with a random index from the first vector and put it into a 2nd vector? But we can see only 1 vector "filenames" where you do some random swapping activity.

Then you have written

> imread is actually to read the whole file in the folder of directory

This function is very important, what does it do? And what do you mean by "read the file"? Do you mean "filename", so the name of the file? Or the contents of the file? And what is the meaning of "folder of directory"? All filenames in one folder? Or subfolder of a directory entry?

> So now my objective is to print out all the file that do not have same filename in the array 2

Again, do we really have 2 arrays(vector)? are they different?

And then, where do you copy the files?

---

So, you see, it is very hard to understand. Even, if people would like to help you, they cannot, because they do not understand you. Better to show a link to your original home work. Then people can help you. Members here on Stack Overflow want to help. But please allow them to do so.

Here I give you an abstract example for the random selection problem and set_difference problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int main() {
    // Define 2 Vectors for filenames

    // This vector is an example for files that could be in a specified directory
    std::vector<std::string> fileNamesInDirectory{"8.jpg","5.jpg", "6.jpg", "9.jpg", "1.jpg", "4.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", };

    // Print the filenames as information for the user
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < fileNamesInDirectory.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << fileNamesInDirectory[i] << "\n";
    }

    // Next: Select randomly a given number of filenames from the above vector

    // So, first get the number of selections. Inform the user
    std::cout << "\nEnter a number of filenames that should be copied randomly. Range: 1-"<< fileNamesInDirectory.size()-1 << "\t";
    size_t numberOfSelectedFileNames{};
    std::cin >> numberOfSelectedFileNames;

    // Check for valid range
    if (numberOfSelectedFileNames == 0 || numberOfSelectedFileNames >= fileNamesInDirectory.size()) {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error. Wrong input '" << numberOfSelectedFileNames << "'\n";
    }
    else {
        // Copy all data from fileNamesInDirectory
        std::vector<std::string> selection{ fileNamesInDirectory };

        // Shuffle the data randomly: Please see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 g(rd());
        std::shuffle(selection.begin(), selection.end(), g);

        // Resize to the number, given by the user
        selection.resize(numberOfSelectedFileNames);

        // Now we have a random list of filenames
        // Show, what we have so far. Now, because we are learning, we will use the range based for
        std::cout << "\n\nOriginal file names:\n";
        for (const std::string& s : fileNamesInDirectory) std::cout << s << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n\nRandomly selected file names:\n";
        for (const std::string& s : selection) std::cout << s << "\n";

        // Sort both vectors
        std::sort(fileNamesInDirectory.begin(), fileNamesInDirectory.end());
        std::sort(selection.begin(), selection.end());

        // Show again to the user:3

        std::cout << "\n\nOriginal file names sorted:\n";
        for (const std::string& s : fileNamesInDirectory) std::cout << s << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n\nRandomly selected file names sorted:\n";
        for (const std::string& s : selection) std::cout << s << "\n";

        // Now, find out the difference of both vectors, meaning, what will not be selected and later copied
        std::vector<std::string> difference{};

        // Calculate the difference with a std::algorithm: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference
        std::set_difference(fileNamesInDirectory.begin(), fileNamesInDirectory.end(), selection.begin(), selection.end(), std::back_inserter(difference));

        std::cout << "\n\nThe following file names have not been selected:\n";
        for (const std::string& s : difference) std::cout << s << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you are more advanced then you can and will use functions from the C++ [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem). That will make life easier . . .

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaination that makes you confuse. I already update original code so that you can test it out for better understanding. if there is any question that make you confuse, i will try my best to explain it. I already stuck at this for days so i do hope you can help me.